# Importing single value from a CSV file not working in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use a Macro that retrieves a single value from a CSV file. I've written a MACRO that works perfectly fine if there is only 1 CSV file, but does not deliver the expected results when I have to run it against more than one file. If there is more than one file it returns the value of the last file in each iteration.

```
%macro reporting_import( full_file_route );


%PUT The Source file route is: &full_file_route;
%PUT ##############################################################;

PROC IMPORT datafile = "&full_file_route"
    out = file_indicator_tmp
    dbms = csv
    replace;
    datarow = 3;
RUN;

data file_indicator_tmp (KEEP= lbl);
    set file_indicator_tmp;
        if _N_ = 1;
        lbl = "_410 - ACCOUNTS"n;
run;

proc sql noprint ;
     select lbl
     into :file_indicator
     from file_indicator_tmp;
quit;

%PUT The Source Reporting period states: &file_indicator;
%PUT ##############################################################;

%mend;
```

This is where I execute the Macro. Each excel file's full route exists as a seperate record in a dataset called "HELPERS.RAW_WAITLIST".

```
data _NULL_;
set HELPERS.RAW_WAITLIST;
  call execute('%reporting_import('||filename||')');
run;
```

In the one example I just ran, The one file contains 01-JUN-2015 and the other 02-JUN-2015. But what the code returns in the LOG file is:

```
The Source file route is: <route...>\FOO1.csv
##############################################################
The Source Reporting period states: Reporting Date:02-JUN-2015  
##############################################################
The Source file route is: <route...>\FOO2.csv
##############################################################
The Source Reporting period states: Reporting Date:02-JUN-2015
##############################################################
```

Does anybody understand why this is happening? Or is there perhaps a better way to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

If I remove the code from the MACRO and run it manually for each input file, It works perfectly. So it must have something to do with the MACRO overwriting values.

Comment: What happens if you don't use call execute and call the macro each time? Also, could your write a data step instead to read the CSV file that way you only read the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CALL EXECUTE has tricky timing issues.  When it invokes a macro, if that macro generates macro variables from data set variables, it's a good idea to wrap the macro call in %NRSTR().  That way call execute generates the macro call, but doesn't actually execute the macro. So try changing your call execute statement to:

```
call execute('%nrstr(%%)reporting_import('||filename||')');
```

I posted a much longer explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749472/sas-macro-coding/27757820#27757820).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too clear on the connections between your files. But instead of importing the CSV files and then searching for your string, couldn't you use a [pipe command](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/61879/HTML/default/viewer.htm#pipe.htm) to save the results of a grep search on your CSV files to a dataset and then read just in the results?

**Update:**

I tried replicating your issue locally and it works for me if I set `file_indicator` with a call symput as below instead of your `into :file_indicator`:

```
data file_indicator_tmp (KEEP= lbl);
  set file_indicator_tmp;
    if _N_ = 1;
    lbl = "_410 - ACCOUNTS"n;
data _null_ ;
  set file_indicator_tmp ;
  if _n_=1 then call symput('file_indicator',lbl) ;
run;
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach and one that I'll surely investigate, but I think that it's making this very simple problem a little bit too complex.